# A continuous surjection from $(0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I am searching for an example of a continuous surjection from $(0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$. Please help me by giving an idea how to construct such a function.

Comment: edit to include what you've tried, what's stopping you

Answer (score 2):

Something like this
[image]
You need the wiggles to get taller and taller as you approach zero so that they get larger than any real value.  You only have a little room, so the wiggles have to get tighter and tighter as you approach zero.